# AutoHotkey IfWinTitle is not working

Tags: autohotkey

I want:

```
  z::6
  x::7
  c::8
```

but only if I'm playing Oblivion (window name: Oblivion)

But right now, no matter how I code it, it always applies to other windows too, not just Oblivion. So I have to click "Suspend Hotkeys" every time I **Alt**+**Tab** to Chrome so I don't accidentally type 6 7 8 instead of z x c. It's really annoying. I've tried so many things, I'm not even going to bother posting the code.

Please don't tell me to RTFM or search online, because I have done that for many months already ;)

Comment: It might not help you to post the code, but it could help others to fully understand what you want.

Answer (score 1):

I would think after "many months" in the documentation you might have come across this... I won't say "RTFM" though :)

Try using the [#IfWinActive command](http://www.autohotkey.com/docs/commands/_IfWinActive.htm).  This allows for all hotkeys below it to be context-sensitive.

```
SetTitleMatchMode, 2

#IfWinActive, Oblivion
  z::6
  x::7
  c::8
```

Answer (score 0):

Intead of using the remapping feature, try do it like this:

```
z::
    WinWait, Oblivion, 
    IfWinNotActive, Oblivion, , Oblivion, 
    WinWaitActive, Oblivion, 

    Send, {6 down}{6 up}
return
```

Comment: This code seems very peculiar. Aside from the dubious formatting, what's with all the `Win...` commands? **1)** `IfWinNotActive, Oblivion, , Oblivion` will **never** be true, since you define the same value for `WinTitle` and `ExcludeTitle`, which cancel each other out. **2)** I assume you want the script to wait until Oblivion is active (a simple `WinWaitActive, Oblivion` would suffice for that purpose). Consequentially, when a user presses `z` and it's not active, the hotkey will wait for the window (e.g. for several hours) and then Send `6`, that can't be desirable.

Comment: The actual `z` will always be blocked, no matter what. And by the way: `Send, {6 down}{6 up}` is the same as `Send, 6` or `Send, {6}` respectively.